# Calculating tabular integrals

Tags: integration

I have troubles in determination of the integrals below.

$$\int \left(1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right) \cdot \sqrt{x\sqrt x} \ dx$$

$$\int \sqrt[3] x+2 \ dx$$

$$\int\frac{1}{\sin^2x\,\cos^2x} \ dx$$

Comment: I edited your post to apply the math formulas. Please check if it's done correctly.
Furthermore, please don't ask multiple questions in one post.
And lastly, what have you tried already?

Comment: Thanks for your help.. i ask only one. :) I tried to find lcd in the last one, but didn't work really well...  as for the first, i tried making the sqrts to x^1/2 and so on, but the result didn't go well as well, I can't really write what I tried, because it will be too hard using the normal keyboard characters.. if you understand what I mean.

Comment: For the last one, have you seen integrating by substitution?

Comment: And im not sure what you mean for your first one. LCD is for me, lowest common divisor, which is not really ment in this context i guess.

Comment: No, I haven't.. it's not meant to be done with that according to the exercise. What about making the integral (sin^2x+cos^2x)/(sin^2x*cos^2x)? Will it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

$$(1)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\left(1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\sqrt{x\sqrt x}=x^{3/4}-x^{-5/4}\,,\,\,\text{and remember:} \int x^n\,dx=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+c\;,\;\;n\neq -1$$

$$(2)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\sqrt[3]x+2=x^{1/3}+2\,\,\,\text{, and read the rightmost part above}$$

$$(3)\;\;\;\;\;\;\frac{1}{\sin^2x\,\cos^2x}=\frac{4}{\sin^22x}....\text{but}\;\;\;(\cot x)'=-\frac{1}{\sin^2x}\ldots$$

Comment: May I ask where did the -5/4 come from? I know sqrt(x) = x^1/2, and the sqrt inside is x^1/2, which makes it x^1/4 or am I wrong?

Comment: $$\sqrt{x\sqrt x}=\sqrt{x^{3/2}}=x^{3/4}$$ $$\frac{x^{3/4}}{x^2}=x^{-5/4}\ldots$$

Comment: Is the answer of second integral equal to = x^4/3 / 4/3 + 2x +c?

Comment: Yes, it is...but please write with LaTeX! in the FAQ section you can find directions. The second integral indeed is $$\frac{3x^{4/3}}{4}+2x +C$$

Comment: Is it possible to make $$ \left(1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right) $$ to be equal to $$ x^{3/4} $$ ?

Comment: Not without some black magic, @user2041143...why?

Comment: So I can use the pre-made formula to calculate $$ \int x^n dx $$

Comment: One more question regarding the last one. Can we use the formula $$ sin^2x+cos^2x=1 $$ so we replace 1 with that and continue the integral? After that, I get final answer to be $$ tgx-ctgx+c $$

Comment: But you can always check by differentiating, @user2041143:$$(\tan x-\cot x+c)'=\frac{1}{\cos^2x}+\frac{1}{\sin^2x}=\frac{\sin^2x+\cos^2x}{\sin^2x\cos^2x}=\frac{1}{\sin^2x\cos^2x}\ldots !$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int \left(1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right) \cdot \sqrt{x\sqrt x} \ dx$$
Hint: 
$$\left(1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right) \cdot \sqrt{x\sqrt x}=x^{3/4}-x^{-5/4}$$

---

$$\int \sqrt[3] x+2 \ dx$$
Hint:
$$\sqrt[3] x+2=x^{1/3}+2$$

---

$$\int\frac{1}{\sin^2x\,\cos^2x} \ dx$$
Hint: 
$$\sin^2x=1-\cos^2x \ \text{and substitute} \ u=cos^2x$$